# smallest value of $k$ for which $a_k$ is $0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_1=10$, $a_2=20$ and define $$a_{n+1}=a_{n-1}-\frac{4}{a_n}$$ for $n \gt 1$. What is the smallest value of $k$ for which $a_k=0?$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $b_n = a_{n+1}a_n$. Then $b_1 = 200$ and $b_{n+1} = b_n - 4$. It follows that $k=51$ is the smallest value for which $b_k = 0$ and 
therefore $k=52$ is the smallest value for which $a_k = 0$.