# $ a_1 = 10 $ and $ a_2 =20$. Given that, $ a_{n+1} = a_{n-1} - (4/(a_n)) $ . Find smallest k for which $a_k= 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

$ a_1 = 10 $ and $ a_2 =20$. Given that, $ a_{n+1} = a_{n-1} - (4/(a_n)) $ . Find smallest k for which $a_k= 0 $

A. Does not exist. 
B. is 200
C. is 50.
D. is 52.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE. Please indicate what you have tried, your thoughts on the problem and where you got stuck. This will help people better tailor their answer to your background and situation. It will also demonstrate that you are interested in your question and not just looking for someone to do your homework for you - Math.SE is not a homework site.

Comment: I'll get you started.  We already have $a_1$ and $a_2$.  So $a_3 = a_1 - 4 / a_2 = 10 - 4 / 20 = 9 \frac {4}{5}$

Comment: What in the world does "solution required" mean?  Interesting problem, rude question.

Comment: Well, I came up with a pattern and it wasn't leading anywhere.

Comment: I apologise if I came across as rude, it wasn't the intent.

Comment: If you came across a pattern, you should post it! I was a bit harsh there, not my intent either. In general, it is not polite to demand solutions from those who are voluntarily answering your question. It is a good problem, you should include what you tried beforehand. I changed my vote to +1

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781047/smallest-value-of-k-for-which-a-k-is-0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$ a_{n+1} = a_{n-1} - \frac{4}{a_n}$$ $$\implies  \large 4=a_{n-1}a_n - a_na_{n+1}  $$
So we can write by a telescoping series;
$$\begin{align} & 4=a_{n-1}a_n - a_na_{n+1} \\ & 4=a_{n-2}a_{n-1} - a_{n-1}a_{n} \\ &4=a_{n-3}a_{n-2} - a_{n-2}a_{n-1} \\ & \ldots \\ & 4=a_1a_2 - a_2a_3  \end{align}$$

By adding the $(n-1)$ sums, we get by cancelling,
$$4(n-1)=a_1a_2-a_na_{n+1}$$ $$\implies \large a_na_{n+1} = -4n+204 \tag1$$

Now, observe that the product $a_na_{n+1}$ first becomes zero for $n=51$. But for $n=50$ using $(1)$, $a_{50}a_{51}=4\not=0$. And since such a product can only be $0$ if either of the terms is $0$, so $a_{51} \not=0$; rather $a_{52}=0$.

But then using $(1)$, $a_{52}a_{53}=-4\not=0 \Rightarrow a_{52}\not=0$ , neither of them, that is.

So this is a contradiction.

Hence the smallest $k$ for which $a_k=0$ does not exist i.e no such $k$ exists for $k \in \mathbb{I^+}$.

Comment: +1 very nice solution. How did you deduce that $a_{50}a_{51}=4$?

Comment: @AndresMejia Well, I just put $n=50$ in the last equation that I developed. And got that result.

Comment: *facepalm,* I need to go do some more problems, I like this a lot :)

Comment: Thank you! 
It was great help.

Comment: @user371530 You're welcome. BTW my previous answer was incomplete, please note the change.

Comment: It is an ISI (B.Math 2011) math problem and the answer says it is 52.

Comment: @user371530 It maybe. That's what it initially looked like to me as well. But then check my solution. Do you find anything that is without logic? Or meaningless addition?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat  if $a_n=0$, then the equation from the OP for $a_{n+1}$ is not well defined.

Comment: @AndresMejia Exactly. A very good point. +1 for your comment. I missed it , don't know why.